# How to force browser to download HUGE mp4 file instead of playing it

Tags: php, server, download

Okay , I know it sounds like duplicate but it's not.
there's a lot of questions and answers about downloading a mp4 file instead of playing it by browser.

my issue is my mp4 has 1GB size and my server has 512 ram and 1 CPU so , this methods are not working for me.

**Here's my current code :**

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
$file = $_GET['target'];
header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.";");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
?>
```

Is there any way to make it happen on a huge file ?

Comment: What about setting headers with `Header` directive in .htaccess and linking the file directly?

Comment: @MichalHynčica I'm just learning man :D

Comment: I haven't tried it that's why I only suggested it in comments. But I believe that if the only reason for using php is setting headers, it would be better to set them with [mod_headers](https://www.who.int/manual/en/mod/mod_headers.html#header) and let the apache handle sending the file instead of opening it in php.

Comment: Also the mime type is supposed to be `application/octet-stream` not octet/stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried downloading the file in chunks, e.g.:

```
$chunk = 256 * 256; // you can play with this - I usually use 1024 * 1024;
$handle = fopen($file, 'rb');
while (!feof($handle))
{
    $data = fread($handle, $chunk);
    echo $data;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
fclose($handle);
```