# PHP Downloading large files more than 1GB wont work

Tags: php, apache, download, xampp, zip

I have a script that creates a zip that results in a size of more than 5GB. Once the zip has been made it then gets download. During the process of the download it say X/5GB but as soon as it reaches 1GB/5GB the download immediately stops and says 1GB/1GB.

Comment: Sounds like a configuration problem - have you checked your relevant php.ini?

Comment: I have made the execution time to be about 1hour and the memory limit to be way above the 5GB.

Comment: Check the error log. Could be "max_execution_time" parameter has too low value.

Comment: The problem only occurs when being downloaded. But when I check the zip file where it was created. There doesn't seem to be any problem with it

Comment: Possible duplicate [download huge file - in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58070029/how-to-force-browser-to-download-huge-mp4-file-instead-of-playing-it/58070228#58070228)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force browser to download HUGE mp4 file instead of playing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58070029/how-to-force-browser-to-download-huge-mp4-file-instead-of-playing-it)